# Best way for BYTE array to HEX string conversion? (to avoid funny characters)

Tags: c

I have an application that needs to take the MsgId from a Websphere MQ message and write that as a file name on the file system....but have the HEX value string....

Note that a MsgId on Websphere MQ is actually a byte array of 24 long, and this is where I think my problem is coming in.

So here are some snippets of the code:

```
 #define MSGID_LEN 24
 #define MSGID_HEX_LEN 48

    ...
    ...
 char *uuid = NULL;
 char *buffer = NULL;
 char msgid_hex[MSGID_HEX_LEN];
 char *pmsgid_hex = msgid_hex;
 char msgid[MSGID_LEN];

 memcpy(msgid, md.MsgId, MSGID_LEN);
 convertMsgIdToHex(pmsgid_hex, msgid);
 uuid = malloc(MSGID_HEX_LEN * sizeof(char));
 memcpy(uuid, pmsgid_hex, MSGID_HEX_LEN);

    ..
    ..

    int convertMsgIdToHex(char *msgid_hex, char msgid[MSGID_LEN]){
        int len = strlen(msgid);
        int i;

        for(i=0; i<len;i++){
            sprintf(msgid_hex, "%02X", (unsigned char)msgid[i]);
            msgid_hex +=2;
        };
    }
```

The problem is that their are sometime funny characters in the MSGID on Wensphere MQ and it seems I do not know how to convert these into there HEX equivalent.

For example, if I debug the application the MsgId is:

**"AMQ QM01        \327\354\254N\027\232\002 "**

And the hex string I get after the function above is:

**"414D5120514D30312020202020202020D7ECAC4E179A0220"**

This is fine, but sometimes I get funny characters like little hearts and symbols and when I try write the HEX string as a file name it works but has "invalid encoding" in the string as well....

What is the correct way I should work here? Should I convert from BYTE array to HEX string? If so do someone have a snippet of code on how I could possible change my function above to work with bytes instead of chars?

Should I be declaring my "char" variables are unsigned chars?

Thanks for the help ;-)

Lynton

Comment: `%02X` should work fine to convert a char to hex.  If you're getting errors I'd suggest you look for a buffer overflow or some such.  You should at the very least check the length of your input string to be sure it's no longer than half the length of your buffer minus 1.  (The minus 1 is because you need to write a null at the end of your buffer, so you need to reserve an extra character for that.)

Comment: A byte array is not a string.  You'll need to get rid of strlen() in that code.  Not a problem, you know the length.  How you generate a filename from the byte array isn't clear, using the hex encoded string should work fine since it only contains [0-9A-F]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `strlen` to determine the message length: `strlen` should be used only for null-terminated strings. Since the message here is in a binary encoding, it may include embedded zeroes (which will cause the message to be truncated) or it may contain no zeroes - which will cause a buffer overflow since you will read past the end of the message.

Since apparently the message length is `MSGID_LEN` here, you should use that for the length.

Additionally, you need to make sure you output buffer is large enough. Its size should be at least `2*MSGID_LEN + 1`: 2 characters for each input byte, plus one for the null terminator.